# enum in json-schema with a (RegEx) pattern

Tags: json, regex, validation, schema, jsonschema

A certain category in my json dataset should be restricted to a limited number of values, so I put them in a list in `enum`. There are two issues:

1. In some cases it is necessary to add an asterisk to the value; this can apply to all values, for instance `water` and `water*` are both valid.
2. One of the values contains additional information indicated by two characters in between brackets, for instance `value(ab)`.

For both issues, it is the easiest to use RegEx patterns, but is it possible to combine `enum` with `pattern`? (I know it is possible to put all possible values in a `pattern` separated by `|`, but that is not ideal.)

```
{
  "category": {
    "enum": ["water", "beer", "wine", "soda([a-z]{0,2})"]
  }
}
```

Valid values are `water`, `water*`, `beer`, `beer*`, `wine`, `wine*`, `soda()`, `soda()*`, and the last two with any combination of two lowercase letters in between the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `anyOf` with `pattern`.

```json
{
  "type": "string", 
  "anyOf": [
    { "pattern": "^water.*" },
    { "pattern": "^beer.*" },
    ...
  ]
}
``
```